# Connecting App engine standard to private ip vm of another gcp project

Tags: google-app-engine, serverless, peer, google-vpc

I am having a Private ip vm in project A with vpc N1 and in project B a vpc N2. Both are peered and I am trying to connect to the private ip vm from project B through app engine standard using a serverless vpc connector. But i not able to connect. If I go with flex and mention the peered network N2 of project B am able to connect. Why? Any thoughts on it

Answer (score 0):

To connect from a serverless environment you gotta configure a [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access); in order to connect within two different projects you have to use a [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), but one of the limitations of a Serverless VPC Access is that it cannot be used with a shared VPC:

> Serverless VPC Access supports communication to VPC networks connected via Cloud VPN and VPC Network Peering. Serverless VPC Access does not support legacy networks or Shared VPC.

Also please be aware that Serverless VPC Access only allows requests to be initiated by the serverless environment. Requests initiated by a VM must use the external address of your serverless service.